# Pattern matching to find last element of list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to find the last element of a list in Scala using pattern matching. I tried following code

```
def last[A](list: List[A]):A = list match {
 case head :: Nil => head
 case head :: tail => last(tail)
 case _ => Nil
 }
```

The last case i.e. `case _ => Nil` is throwing error as type mismatch (found Nil.type require A)

I know this problem can be solved using other methods but using only pattern matching is there a way to solve this?

As the list is of generic type so I cannot replace `Nil` with default value of type A which can only be determined at runtime.

Removing this line: `case _ => Nil`  is obviously working but with a warning that it will fail in case of Nil argument.

So, how can I handle Nil argument in this scenario?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can pattern match with `:+`.

```
def last[A](list: List[A]) = list match {
  case init :+ last => Some(last)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Nice.  And, of course, tail-recursive.  IMHO this should become the correct answer.

Comment: Is there a similar extractor just for the last element? Namely, `_  :+ last` doesn't match singleton lists like `List(1)`.

Comment: @ComFreek `val _ :+ last = List(1)` works for me though.

Comment: Can anybody explain please how does `:+ last` becames value with type `A`? Reading this example my expectation is `List[A]`.

Comment: @Sergii It's just a [custom extractor](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/collection/package.scala#L74-L81). Nothing magical going on.

Answer (score 4):

As you are not sure whether your list does contain any object you should handle such situation in general way. I'd suggest returning option type in your `last` method as follows:

```
def last[A](list: List[A]): Option[A] = list match {
    case head :: Nil => Some(head)
    case head :: tail => last(tail)
    case _ => None
}
```

Then in your code you can use monad-like interface to work with the result. You can either use `map` and process data in provided function, or use `get` method on option in case you are absolutely sure the list was not empty.

Answer (score 4):

use `Option[T]` to return the result, so if there is some element return `Some(lastElement)` otherwise `Option.empty`

Example,

```
  def last[A](list: List[A]): Option[A] = list match {
    case head :: Nil => Option(head)
    case head :: tail => last(tail)
    case _ => Option.empty
  }

  it("returns last element") {

    assert(last(List("apple")) == Some("apple"))
    assert(last(List("apple", "mango")) == Some("mango"))
    assert(last(List()) == Option.empty)
    assert(last(List()) == None)

  }
```

**How to access the `Option[T]`?**

```
last(List("In absentia", "deadwind")) match {
  case Some(lastValue) => println(s"Yayy there was lastValue = ${lastValue}") //prints Yayy there was lastValue = deadwind
  case None => println("Oops list was empty")
}

last(List()) match {
  case Some(lastValue) => println(s"Yayy there was lastValue = ${lastValue}")
  case None => println("Oops list was empty") //prints Oops list was empty
}

// or using map
last(List("In absentia", "deadwind")).map(lastValue => print(s"lastValue is ${lastValue}"))
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify something similar to "Null" here (like in Java) for generic types (so that we can avoid using Option) ?

Comment: Not recommended, because the idea is to remove concept of `null`. The last element could either be `some value` or `empty`. Are you having any problem manipulating the returned `Option` value?? `returnedValue match {}` is the way to process the returned last value

Comment: Shashank, you might see such a thing in rare cases where it makes a huge difference in performance, but it would not be idiomatic Scala.  Note that in this case you'd have to constrain A to be an AnyRef, i.e. `last[A <: AnyRef]`.

Comment: @AmigoNico: yeah it makes sense if we think this way.. thanks